# Android 4.4 Rom Build with Root Access for all APK

Tags: android, linux, android-kernel

I'm trying to compile (build) android ROM (KitKat 4.4.2) and encountered a permission related issue.

I've got the rom working properly on the device, however, I am looking for ways to allow one of the application to gain permission to perform reboot. After several research, I've included the Reboot permission for the application. However, according to my research I still need to have root access.

Anyone know where I need to modify in Android ROM source code (4.4.2) so that my application (which I'll distribute it along with the ROM) can have the ability to issue reboot command?

(Note: My application is fully functional on previous generation hardware which is running Android 4.2.2.)

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Can your app be run as a system app? Did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, 4.2.2 and 4.4.2 treat system app in different way. In 4.2.2 if you include the .apk file into app folder when you build the rom, it will be given ability to perform reboot command (i'm assuming this means it got system level permission). In 4.4.2, there's a special app folder which only apps live inside that folder during the ROM deployment will given system level permission.

I simply move the program into that special app folder and everything become functional.